# Split Word into Two and Check Existence in Comma Separated String Sequence

Tags: java, substring

I have a string array for example:

```
new String[] = {"powerhouse", "p, pow, power, house, pose, poser"};
```

My goal is to split the first entry in the array in this case `powerhouse` into any two words and check them against the second entry, which serves as a dictionary of words.

Here's my implementation so far:

```
public static String[] convertWordsToArray(String input){
  String[] wordArr = null;
  wordArr = input.split(",");
  return wordArr;
}

public static String splitEm(String[] strArr) {
    String fw = strArr[0];
    String sw = strArr[1];

    String[] arrOne = convertWordsToArray(fw);
    System.out.println(arrOne.length);

    String[] dict = convertWordsToArray(sw);
    System.out.println(dict.length);

    for(int i = 0; i < dict.length - 1; i++) {
         String mWord = fw.split(i, i + 1);
         System.out.println(mWord);
    }

    // Edit Starts Here, tried to substring it but nothing prints in log
      for(int i = 0; i < arrOne.length; i++) {
        String mWord = fw.substring(0, i);
        System.out.println(mWord);
      }

    return ""; // empty for now
}
```

I am stuck at the part where the first word has to be split. Should I use two loops, one for the first word and the other for the dictionary? I know that somehow the dictionary has to be converted to a list or array list to avail the `.contains()` method. How do I go about this? Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. What do you mean by _split  first entry in the array in this case powerhouse into any two words_ ?

Comment: I mean that, you have an array of two entries..first entry needs to be spit into two words and checked against the second entry which acts as a list/dictionary. For example in powerhouse(first entry) when broken down into any two words we can get power, house, (or pose) and these words are already present in the SE(second entry/dictionary).

Comment: My problem is how to split the first entry into any two words. Thanks

Comment: Are "pwhse" and "hrwp" also valid substrings? Meaning you want to check if `string[0]` contains all chars which are present in `string[1]`, well except from space and comma?

Comment: No, the only valid substrings should be those in the SE/dictionary. Thanks

Comment: But I would still like to know your approach for substringing it

Comment: I am a bit confused. You say **you want to check** but you are trying to return a string instead of a boolean and additionally  **pose** is in your case a valid substring but in my opinion pose is not a substring of powerhose, indepently it contains some chars of **powerhouse**

Comment: Yes, independently but I was just making the point with that. The string I should return is either "Words Found" or "Not Possible" but that's going to be after checking for containership

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need something like this?

```
String s = "powerhouse";
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
    for(int j = i+1; j <= s.length(); j++){
        list.add(s.substring(i,j));
    }
}

System.out.println(list);
```

I assume you need something like below:

- Split second string at each `,` or even better using regex to trim
  spaces before or after `,`
- check if each part of the splited entry fro above point is made of
  only the chars contained in the first entry of your input

example

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String[] test1 = {"powerhouse", "p, pow, power, house, pose, poser"};
    String[] test2 = {"powerhouse", "p, xyz, power, house, pose, poser"};
    System.out.println(check(test1));
    System.out.println(check(test2));
}
static boolean check(String[] input){
    String firstEntry = input[0];
    String[] dictionary = input[1].split("\\s*,\\s*");
    for(int i = 0; i < dictionary.length; i++){
        if(!dictionary[i].matches("["+firstEntry+"]+")){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

this will print true for the first case and false for the second as "xyz" is not a valid subpart/substring according to your discription

Comment: Thanks, I have converted the dictionary from words to array then to list but how do I check for the substring in either the array or array converted to list?

Comment: Very concise, I'm indebted to you guys, What does this syntax "["+firstEntry+"]+" mean pls?

Comment: @Nzadibe it is a character class used in regular expressions. So for example if you want to match a `B` or a `L`, you can use `[BL]`. You could use this in `[BL]ook` to match either `Book` or `Look`. The plus sign at the end means one or more characters from the given character class.  So `[powerhouse]+` matches any string which has at least the length of one and contains any letters from the given inside those square brackets

Answer (score 3):

If anyone want the solution for PHP language, then you can use below code:

```
function ArrayChallenge($strArr) {

  $dictWords = explode( ',', $strArr[1] );
  $strLength = strlen($strArr[0]);

  $output = 'not possible';

  for( $i = 1; $i < $strLength; $i++ ){

    $firstStr = substr($strArr[0], 0, $i);
    $lastStr = substr($strArr[0], $i, $strLength);

    if ( in_array( $firstStr, $dictWords ) && in_array( $lastStr, $dictWords ) ) {
      $output = $firstStr . ',' . $lastStr;
      break;
    }
    
  }

  return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
public class Stack {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] str = {"powerhouse", "p, pow, power, house, pose, poser"};
        String firstPart = str[0];
        String secondPart = str[1];
        boolean contain = isContain(firstPart, secondPart);
        System.out.println(contain);
    }

    private static boolean isContain(String firstPart, String secondPart) {

        for (int i = 0; i < firstPart.length(); i++) {
            String firstWord = firstPart.substring(0, i);
            String secondWord = firstPart.substring(i, firstPart.length());
            List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(secondPart.trim().split("\\s*,\\s*"));              
            if (strings.contains(firstWord) && strings.contains(secondWord)) return true; if you want to check both words use this
            //if (strings.contains(firstWord) || strings.contains(secondWord)) return true; if you want to check any(one) word from two words use this
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I appreciate your effort but the substring should be dynamic like @Eritrean's answer

Comment: I can update with dynamic sub-string, is it necessary?

Comment: Yes, please do so

Comment: @Nzadibe Ok, I will

Comment: @Nzadibe do you need to check both words or 1st word?